# kable_styling() weird interaction with dark RStudio themes

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, kable, kableextra

I recently started using Rmarkdown for my R coding, and I found it extremely useful. However, I have the following issue:

When I want to show tables behind the code (not in the output, but on the rmarkdown code itself), and I use the option `kable_styling()` from `kableExtra` package to display a table, if I have a dark theme activated (ie. Tomorrow Night Bright), the table apperas with a white shadow that makes it hard to read (see picture below):

[image: Example with dark theme]

However, this does not happen when I use a light theme (see picture below):

[image: Example with light theme]

Does anyone know why this happens or how could I fix it? I have already tried to change the output format and a bunch of stuff. If I remove the kable_styling() option the table is correctly displayed, but not the way I want it to be formatted.

Thanks in advance and sorry if I wasn´t clear when posting the question, it is the first time I do this.

Comment: I've always had this issue too. Never actually looked into it, so I'd be really curious if there is a solution that lets you view the stylized table with a dark theme!